# How to inject two variables next to each other separated with a space?

Tags: ruby, haml, erb, slim-lang

The expected `HTML` result is as follows:

```
<li>description1 name1</li>
<li>description2 name2</li>
<!-- ... -->
```

Where the list of `description`-`name` is known and can be iterated over.

I tried to do:

```
li
  = tool.description
  | &nbsp;
  = tool.name
```

or

```
li
  = "#{tool.description}&nbsp;#{tool.name}"
```

but it seems like an ugly way to achieve that.

Is there any other and elegant solution?

Comment: What happens when you do just this `"#{tool.description} #{tool.name}"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the not breaking space is not being rendered.

Comment: Strange! I guess you already looked up the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation directly in both Slim and Haml, so you don’t need to use `=` and quote the whole string.

In Slim, you could do:

```
li #{tool.description}&nbsp;#{tool.name}
```

and in Haml the only difference is you just need to add the lead `%`:

```
%li #{tool.description}&nbsp;#{tool.name}
```